# How to supply constructor argument to useFactory lambda function in root module providers array? (Angular 8)

Tags: angular

I am trying to create a generic service, something like:

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class AppAsyncService<T> {

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  create(link: string, resource: T | T[]) {
    return this.http.post<T | T[]>(link, resource);
  }

  read(link: string) {
    return this.http.get<T | T[]>(link);
  }

  update(link: string, resource: T | T[]) {
    return this.http.put<T | T[]>(link, resource);
  }

  delete(link: string) {
    return this.http.delete<T>(link);
  }

  patch(link: string, resource: T | T[]) {
    return this.http.patch<T | T[]>(link, resource);
  }
}
```

My root module providers array:

```
providers: [
    {
      provide: 'PersonService',
      useFactory: () => new AppAsyncService<Person>(HttpClient),
      multi: true,
      deps: [HttpClient]
    }
  ]
```

Though, there's an error on the HttpClient in the constructor of the useFactory lambda: "Argument of type 'typeof HttpClient" is not assignable to parameter of type 'HttpClient'.

Anyone have any ideas what the reason is, or simply how to accomplish this task?

Further, is there a better way to implement generic services easily and with minimal code?

Comment: Can you just write this `useFactory: (httpClient: HttpClient) => new AppAsyncService<Person>(httpClient),` ?

Comment: This has gotten rid of the error, thank you. My code is not in a compilable state, refactoring, so I can't test it. I removed the multi: true as well since it don't think it applies here. If you change your response from a comment I can accept it.

Comment: Glad it worked. I posted an answer with some docs with bit more details on how to use `useFactory` method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per documentation on Factory Providers [here](https://angular.io/guide/dependency-injection-providers#factory-providers) and [here](https://angular.io/api/core/FactoryProvider) you can see in the examples the way to use `useFactory` with parameters. In your case, this is how you can solve your problem:

```js
providers: [
  {
    provide: 'PersonService',
    useFactory: (httpClient: HttpClient) => new AppAsyncService<Person>(httpClient),
    multi: true,
    deps: [HttpClient]
  }
]
```

Hope this helps.